# Can I determine which tasks in collection have subtask without additional API queries?

Tags: asana-api

I'm trying to deep-copy a task with nested subtasks using the API. Currently, I'm querying the subtasks endpoint for each task in my tree.

Is there any way to know if a task is going to have subtasks without having to hit the `subtasks` endpoint for each task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't. We might make it possible to query subtasks on the task list in future, but it requires adding second level pagination which we'd need to design and that isn't on our roadmap.